# HTML Playing Base 64 encoded audio with angularJS with Error: [$interpolate:noconcat]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, audio

So I am trying to get my web app to play base64 encoded audio. This is the code I am using:

```
<audio controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source  ng-src="data:audio/mp3;base64,{{article.MOI}}">
</audio>
```

The problem is I am getting this error:

```
angular.js:11655 Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=data%3Aaudio%2Fmp3%3Bbase64%2C%7B%7Barticle.MOI%7D%7D
```

The weird thing is I am also displaying base64 encoded images with the following line of code:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{article.Image_Front}}" >
```

Where the images are able to display correctly when I comment out the audio portion. In addition if I replace the call to article.MOI with the actual base64 encoded string I can get the audio to play. I've looked and tried using

```
$scope.recordings = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(myData);
```

in my angularjs code but I still get the same errors.

Comment: so I can hard code the audio to work using `ng-src = "data:audio/mp3;base64,(the encoded base64 string)"` it's only when I try to insert the $scope variable I have assigned in my js does it give me the error

Answer (score 0):

Try to create in the controller, a variable like the following:

```
$scope.test = "data:audio/mp3;base64," + $scope.article.MOI
```

and binding this variable to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem playing the audio using Firebase. This worked for me.

In my controller i had:

```
$scope.testAudio =  $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("data:audio/mp3;base64," + $scope.article.MOI)
```

In my HTML:

```
<audio controls class="playback" ng-src="{{testAudio}}"></audio>
```